# Curious about the weird initialization syntax of body: Some View in ContentView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5

The default code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }
    
}
```

I guess the code above should be equivalent to the following code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View = {
        Text("Hello World!")
    }()
    
}
```

Or even more comprehensive:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View = {
        () -> Text in
            return Text("Hello World!")
    }()
    
}
```

I just want to know where I can find a reference to this initialization syntax for `body` in the first code block? I didn't find any description of this syntax in the closures chapter of `the swift programming lanauage` book at `swift.org`.

Comment: Hi and welcome, can you clarify what the particular problem you're trying to solve is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have incorrectly identified the property `body` as a stored property. It's actually a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259). Changing it to a stored property would change the code's semantics significantly.

It is equivalent to:

```
var body: some View {
    get {
        return Text("Hello World!")
    }
}
```

The `return` and `get` can be omitted in a [Shorthand Property Declaration](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID608) and a [read-only computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID261).

> If the entire body of a getter is a single expression, the getter implicitly returns that expression.

> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by removing the get keyword and its braces