# type keyword in property braces

Tags: swift

Watching 'Compose custom layouts with SwiftUI' and came across a struct with a property defined as follows:

```
struct Pet : Identifiable, Equatable {
 ...
 var id : String { type }
}
```

What is the purpose of 'type' in this context?

Google search not very helpful.

TIA

Comment: This is a computed property. Essentially a function that runs when you call `pet.id` and returns the `type`. https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/computed-property/

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65717091/5133585 Note that `type` is not a keyword. It's the name of a property declared somewhere.

Comment: If you use XCode, what's the color of `type`. It's not "pink/red" (if you use the defaults colors), no? So it's not a keyword. Does it have the same color as a property?